# Regex that handles quoted strings and double quote for inches

Tags: c#, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I am writing a little search for a website's product catalog, and I am using regex to determine if there are any strings like "exact search phrase" included in the text from the search text box. The regex that I am currently using is:

```
List<string> searchTermList = searchTerm.Trim().ToLower().Split(new Char[] { ' ' }).ToList();

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(searchTerm, "\"([^\"]*)\""))
{
//irrelevant code
}
```

This code works great for me until I search for something like:
`8" tortilla "stone ground"`

The result I would like as a match would be
`"stone ground"`

but instead I am getting
`" tortilla "`.

The other posts I found for similar questions were escaping the double quote for inches, but I don't have any way to reliably escape quotes like those examples. The best option of the other articles I found was to escape it if it follows a number, but users could search for things like `"burger 3-1"` in quotes, which would be incorrect to escape the last quote in that case.

What I would like is some way to tell if the string inside a set of quotes is preceded by a space or an empty string (if the only search text is a phrase in quotes), but I am inexperienced and struggling with regex, and I feel like it is my best option for tackling something like this. Any help/pointers?

Comment: Can you use `[^0-9]\"` to find a `"` not preceded by a number? Or what about `\s\"` for a `"` preceded by white space?

Comment: No. I included the "burger 3-1" example above where someone may search for an exact phrase that ends in a number, so in cases like that, I would still want the second quote to be found.

Comment: Sorry, misread that bit

Comment: I think something like the \s\" is what I would be looking for if it is preceded by a space character or by nothing. Would preceded by nothing be considered a white space?

Comment: I don't think this can be solved in pure regex. You might be able to do it using a match evaluator that excludes matches that look like inches, and then try to pair up the remaining matches.

Comment: I have a problem I think I can solve with a regex...  Now I have two problems. :)

Comment: What is the search system that you're going to send these terms to? The "real" text search systems like Lucene or SQL FTS may strip out the quote and double-quote characters anyway, so you may just want to strip number-followed-by-quote out of the search string entirely, which is easier than what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (updated)

First use this expression to find and replace (in javascript) all the strings that are of the pattern "9" "9.9" "9-9" to the pattern "9' "9.9' "9-9'

```
\"[0-9.-]*\"
```

Next replace all

```
([^a-z,0-9,',"])([\s]*)\"
```

with just a single ". This will remove all unwanted spaces.

Then take this new formatted string and apply

```
 \"[^\s]([^\"]*)[^\s]\"
```

This takes care of all the scenarios. Just ensure that you take the original string into a new variable and play with else you will end up modifying the original value.

Here is the sample string I used to test the above expressions. I did not have the time to write the javascript function itself. Please post the function if you get it to work using the above expressions.

8" "bosch grinder" , bosch "8" grinder" , and "bosch grinder      " 8" "99" "9.9" "9-7"

A website I use to test out my regular expressions is http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: Better, but not perfect. eg, if the inches is inside the quote: `bosch "8" grinder"`

Comment: It's looking like this answer is the route I will have to take for now. `8" "bosch grinder"` , `bosch "8" grinder"` , and `"bosch grinder" 8"` could all be possibilities, and I'm not really seeing any way to accommodate all three of them in my situation. This is the best option for me at this point.

Comment: Educate your users to use proper grammar structure. Also, during data input, you can do the same validation and show a meaningful message to ensure input data is of good quality. Don't always try to solve for bad data or structure, try to avoid it in the first place.

Comment: @BrianReischl let me know what you think about the updated solution I have posted.

Comment: I think it's better, but I still don't think this problem is really appropriate for regex in the first place.